# Instruction execution order by cuda driver

Tags: cuda

The following piece of code

```
asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(start) :: "memory");
asm volatile("ld.global.ca.u64 data, [%0];"::"l"(po):"memory");
asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(stop) :: "memory");
```

looks like this in the SASS code

```
/*0420*/                   CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO ;                                           /* 0x0000000000027805 */
/*0430*/                   LDG.E.64.STRONG.CTA R4, [R4] ;                                  /* 0x0000000004047381 */
/*0440*/                   CS2R R6, SR_CLOCKLO ;                                           /*
```

I want to be sure that the scheduler issues the second CS2R **after** the LDG instruction and **not** earlier due to any any optimization like out-of-order execution.
How can I be sure about that?

UPDATE:

Based on Greg's suggestion, I added a dependent instruction which looks like

```
  asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(start) :: "memory");
  asm volatile("ld.global.ca.u64 data, [%0];"::"l"(po):"memory");
  asm volatile("add.u64 %0, data, %0;":"+l"(sink)::"memory");
  asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(stop) :: "memory");
```

where `uint64_t sink = 0;` is defined. Still I see only one LDG between CS2R instructions. I expected to see an IADD instruction also since I am reading `data` again. I think I wrote the asm add instruction incorrectly, but don't know any more.

Comment: You can't and I don't think it is reasonable to imagine that in-kernel timing can have single instruction resolution

Comment: A CUDA GPU is not an out-of-order machine. All instructions are issued in the order in which the compiler has created.  You only need to inspect the compiled code. The GPU scheduler will not reorder instructions with respect to a particular thread or warp.  Instructions are issued per-warp, and there is also no guarantee that the warp scheduler will issue the second CS2R instruction immediately after (i.e. in the next available issue slot) the LDG instruction.  It may issue other instructions, from other eligible warps, in between the LDG instruction and the CS2R instruction, for a given warp.

Comment: Make sure you compile to a concrete `sm_XY` architecture where you can check the resulting SASS code as Robert has pointed out. If you generate PTX for just-in-time compilation by the driver (`compute_XY`), then you don't have the means to check the resulting code as it could potentially be different the next time you run it.

Comment: The sequence above will measure the issue latency between the two CS2R. The latency will depend on (a) priority of the warp --> does warp scheduler issue these three instruction back to back, (b) stall due to instruction fetch if instruction sequence cross icache lines, and (c) if LSU pipe is throttled == warp_cant_issue_mio_throttle. If you want to measure LDG execution latency then you have to stick another instruction between the LDG and final CS2R that has a dependency on R4.

Comment: @tera: The command is `nvcc -arch=sm_70 -Xptxas -O3,-v,-dlcm=ca -o run run.cu` on TitanV.

Comment: @GregSmith: please see the updated post.

Comment: CS2R is a fixed latency instruction. CC 1.* - 7.* will execute the instruction sequence in order. The first sequence measures instruction issue latency between the two mov.u64. The second sequence approximately measures the LDG execution latency. There are no additional commands that you can provide at PTX to force the scheduler to issue the instructions as early as possible. If the kernel has high occupancy additional cycles will be counted between the mov.u64 that include cycles the warp was eligible but not selected or stalled on no instruction or a math or mio throttle.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean the second sequence is closer to the concept of "load latency" although both asm sequences generate similar SASS codes. Is that right? I still wonder why you said that the first sequence `measures the issue latency between two CS2R`? If we assume that the clock register value also contains the latency of the CS2R instruction itself (since the instruction must be retired to get the value), the first sequence is actually measuring LDG plus CS2R latency. Assuming CS2R latency is low, the time between start and stop (first and second CS2R) shows LDG latency. No?

Comment: many activities on the GPU are pipelined, including memory accesses.  The `LDG` instruction expects to retrieve something from global memory, and deposit it in a GPU register.  If you want to time the amount of time it takes to issue the `LDG` instruction to the load/store unit (an amount of time that could be low, perhaps as low as 1 clock), then you don't need the extra dependent instruction in the timing region.

Comment: If, OTOH, you are wanting to discover the amount of time it takes to actually retrieve that item from global memory and deposit it in a register, that will typically be a longer time, and it will require a dependent instruction in the timing region. Neither of these methods are guaranteed to give you the minimum time measurement, but both will upper bound what the minimum time measurement might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA GPUs compute capability 1.0 - 7.x will issue instructions for a warp in order. The special purpose registers clock and clock64 can be used to time sections of code by reading the register before and after a sequence of instructions.

This can be useful to estimate the number of cycles that it took to issue a sequence of instructions for a single warp.

**CASE 1 : Instruction Issue Latency**

clock64 reads are inserted before and after a sequence of instructions. In the case below clock64 reads wrap a single global load. This style estimates the instruction issue latency of the global load instruction. The warp can be stalled between the start and end CS2R increasing the duration. Stall reasons can include the following:
- not_selected - the warp scheduler selected a higher priority warp
- no_instruction - LDG was on a new instruction cache line and the warp is stalled until the cache line is fetched
- mio_throttle - LDG instruction cannot be issued as the instruction queue for the Load Store Unit was full.
- lg_throttle - LDG instruction cannot be issued as the instruction queue for the Load Store Unit has reached a local/global watermark.

In order to increase accuracy it is recommended to measure a sequence of instructions as opposed to a single instruction.

PTX

```
asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(start) :: "memory");
asm volatile("ld.global.ca.u32 data, [%0];"::"l"(po):"memory");
asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(stop) :: "memory");
```

SASS (SM_70)

```
/*0420*/                   CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO ;
/*0430*/                   LDG.E.64.STRONG.CTA R4, [R4] ;
/*0440*/                   CS2R R6, SR_CLOCKLO ;
```

**CASE 2: Instruction Execution Latency**

A clock64 read is inserted before a sequence of instructions. A set of instructions that guarantee completion of the sequence of instruction and a clock64 read is inserted after the sequence of instructions. In the case below an integer add is inserted before the last read that is dependent on the value from the global load. This technique can be used to estimate the execution duration of the global load.

PTX

```
asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(start) :: "memory");
asm volatile("ld.global.ca.u32 data, [%0];"::"l"(po):"memory");
asm volatile("add.u32 %0, data, %0;":"+l"(sink)::"memory");
asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(stop) :: "memory");
```

SASS (SM_70)

```
/*0420*/                   CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO ;
/*0430*/                   LDG.E.64.STRONG.CTA R4, [R4] ;
/*0440*/                   IADD R4, R4, 1 ;
/*0450*/                   CS2R R6, SR_CLOCKLO ;
```

**DIAGRAM**

The measurement period for Case 1 and Case 2 is shown in the wave form diagram. The diagram shows the CS2R and IADD instructions taking 4 cycles to execute. The CS2R instructions read the time on the 3rd cycle.

[image]

For Case 1 the measured time may be as small as 2 cycles.
For Case 1 the measured time includes the load from global memory. If the load hits in the L1 cache then the time is in the 20-50 cycles else the time is likely greater than 200 cycles.

**WARNING**

In practice this type of instruction issue or instruction execution latency is very hard to implement. These techniques can be used to write micro-benchmarks or time large sequences of code. In the case of micro-benchmarks it is critical to understand and potentially isolate other factors such as warp scheduling, instruction cache misses, constant cache misses, etc.

The compiler does not treat a read of clock/clock64 as an instruction fence. The compiler is free to move the read to an unexpected location. It is recommended to always inspect the generated SASS code.

Compute Capability 6.0 and higher supports instruction level preemption. Instruction level preemption will result in unexpected results.